# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression status = 'Available'

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am working a C# Windows Application Form connecting to MS Access.
I am filling the datagridview with a specific query but this happened

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Model WHERE Status = 'AVAILABLE''.

on this query

```
OleDbDataAdapter daAvailable = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Type, Brand, Model, SerialNo, Status, Remarks, RAM, HDD, ODD, VideoCard, PS FROM Available ORDER BY Type, Brand, Model WHERE Status = 'AVAILABLE'", cnn);
```

What should I do?

Here's my code

```cs
OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\james\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Vault\Vault\VaultDatabase.accdb");
DataSet dstAvailable = new DataSet();
DataSet dstData = new DataSet();
DataSet dstDeployment = new DataSet();
DataSet dstLog = new DataSet();


public void FillAvailable(DataGridView dgv)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter daAvailable = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Type, Brand, Model, SerialNo, Status, Remarks, RAM, HDD, ODD, VideoCard, PS FROM Available ORDER BY Type, Brand, Model WHERE Status = 'AVAILABLE'", cnn);
    daAvailable.Fill(dstAvailable);
    dgv.DataSource = dstAvailable.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: AVAILABLE is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this

```
public void FillAvailable(DataGridView dgv)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter daAvailable = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Type, Brand, Model, SerialNo, Status, Remarks, RAM, HDD, ODD, VideoCard, PS FROM Available  WHERE Status = 'AVAILABLE' ORDER BY Type, Brand, Model", cnn);
    daAvailable.Fill(dstAvailable);
    dgv.DataSource = dstAvailable.Tables[0];
}
```

**Order By Comes After Where **

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` clause should be after the `WHERE` clause in SQL

So your query should be:

```
OleDbDataAdapter daAvailable = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Type, Brand, Model, SerialNo, "+
     "Status, Remarks, RAM, HDD, ODD, VideoCard, PS " + 
     "FROM Available " +
     "WHERE Status = 'AVAILABLE' "+
     "ORDER BY Type, Brand, Model", cnn);

     //The above query is broken down on multiple lines for clarity
```

Answer (score 1):

> ORDER BY

is always after the WHERE clause, it should be:

```
OleDbDataAdapter daAvailable = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Type, Brand, Model, SerialNo, Status, Remarks, RAM, HDD, ODD, VideoCard, PS FROM Available WHERE Status = 'AVAILABLE'  ORDER BY Type, Brand, Model", cnn);
```